# How do I apply a GREP style a "$" before the first ENSH and nothing after?

Tags: grep, adobe-indesign

Important: a "$" before the first ENSH is optional.

New to GREP. I work on retail ads and trying to figure out how to accommodate client styling rules in my existing paragraph styles. Currently, we use multiple ENSH's to switch character styles in our listings.

So far, no matter what I do, I can only get the style to apply all "$." Below is what I am trying to create with my paragraph style.

> **Example:**
>
> 2/$4.00 **[ENSH]** product name **[ENSH]** after xx/xx/xxxx 2/$5.00
>
> *(character style 1 [ENSH] character style 2 [ENSH] character style 3)*
>
> The "$" in the example above needs to end up superscripted via GREP (apply new character style). I can't just apply to all dollar signs in the string because subsequent "$" after the first ENSH need to remain the same character style as the the text in the respective portion of the string.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the first character style
2. Create a superscript character style say "dollar" that will inherit from the first character style
3. Create second character style
4. Create last character style
5. Use screenshot settings to apply styles.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your insight. My only issue is that I need only the first $ to change to an alternate character style but the second one needs to stay whatever character style is already applied.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Then the idea is : 
1. Create a "normal" character style
2. Create the first character style (green) 
3. Create a superscript character style say "dollar" that will inherit from the first character style
4. Create second character style (red)
5. Create last character style (blue)

6. add Grep styles like \$ => dollar
   That will apply to all $'s.
7. add Grep style so teh last segment with dollar will have a normal style
8. add other grep styles.

HTH